# Can't get JQuery to make an element draggable

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to get familiar with JQuery and thought I'd give making a div draggable a try with a simple little project. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="UI_Theme/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
    <script src="UI_Theme/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="UI_Theme/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#dragme" ).draggable();
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body
        {
            background-color:#4D4D4D;
        }
        #dragme
        {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dragme">
        <font color="black" size="2">Drag this!</font>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've followed a few different JQuery tutorials on the subject to the letter. Despite my best efforts, the element #dragme still isn't draggable. Im not getting any console output or error messages of any kind, either.

Comment: You should check whether the jQuery version you are using supports this or not.

Comment: It works fine for me as well.  The only thing I see that could do it is that the links to you scripts and stylesheets are looking in the same dir that the file is sitting in.

Answer (score 2):

works fine in [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/wpHMH/). Only difference was I used 
jQuery 1.7.2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dragme" ).draggable();
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me as well in my Codepen sketch: http://cdpn.io/ChsKz. Trying use their CDN to serve your jquery scripts, rather than keeping locally and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I figured it out. I was using a bad JQuery file. Downloaded a fresh one and now it works perfectly. Thanks.